# How to get C# code behind variable value in javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

How to get c# code behind variable value in javascript?
I have declared a variable in page load.
I want that variable value in javascript.

**Javascript**

[image]

**Code C#**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needs to be at the class level. As your code is now, by the time the page is being rendered that variable is long gone out of scope

```
public class Whatever{

  public string OrderID { get; set; }
```

Make it a property too, if your plan is for it to be public as your naming (capital O) implies

Answer (score 0):

You can keep it in hidden input field and access that hidden field value in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot interact between client-side and server-side without sending an HTTP request to the server.

you cannot assign as javascript variable directly to the code-behind.

what you can do is like

create a hidden field variable in the client side as

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfVariable" runat="server" />
```

and in the javascript, you can assign some value to the hidden variable as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var somefunction = function () {
            var hfVariable = document.getElementById('<%= hfVariable.ClientID %>');
            hfVariable.value = 'value';
        }
    </script>
```

and you can read the hidden field variable in the code behind as

```
string variable = hfVariable.Value;
```

Comment: I believe this will work with the exception of the call to getElementById('hfVariable'), I believe it should be getElementById('<%= hfVariable.ClientID %>').

Comment: @tdinpsp Yes, you're right. Actually, I forgot about that. Thank you. I corrected my mistake.